# Insert YouTube link and show only ID

Tags: php, mysql, youtube

I don't know where to start. I've added a YouTube page and show YouTube page.

I can insert YouTube link into my MySQL. My script is only working when I use this part:
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[XXXXXXXXXXX]`

I want to insert the whole video link of YouTube.

Cause I'm using the embed source of YouTube, If I insert the YouTube link script needs to show only the video ID but the the whole link still showing up in MySQL

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$nbbb["youtube"].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Still don't get it what you are trying to say.

Comment: @RahilWazir When I insert a yt link for e.x. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[XXXXXXXXXXX]` into mysql, and when select from mysql he only shows up `[XXXXXXXXXXX]`

Comment: Mine is a simple solution. Unsure why someone downvoted a simple working answer with simple logic that can be applied elsewhere. Regex would work but is overkill for what you are trying to achieve in a controlled enviroment.

Comment: @MattTheNinja Then help vote up the simple answers , haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use easy substring function

```
     $fullurl = fromdatabase//whatever that is your full url.
     $videoid=substr($fullurl,-11);
     echo"<iframe......" . $videoid . ".....";
```

This works for all string that have last 11 digit as the youtube video id.

Cheers

Comment: Yes but OP mentioned that he used only that url , I provide as much as he needs,it's way simpler to use substr. He could adapt it to suite his needs. BTW,you are right. +1

Comment: Script is working only with https, cause its 32 char. Is it possible to string more

Comment: Of course, for normal http, use 31 instead of 32.You can count the character from the beginning until "=" for other purposes. see http://th1.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: I can't use     `$videoid=substr($fullurl,32,11);
    $videoid=substr($fullurl,31,11);` is there another way? Sorry bothering you, I'm new to this function.

Comment: Why?,error? You could use $videoid=substr($fullurl,-11); See my new edits, it works for all url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.

This will work for all kind of youtube urls:

- sub-domain or without subdomain
- youtu.be urls
- https & http
- /v/ links

```
/**
 * get youtube video ID from URL
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string Youtube video id or FALSE if none found. 
 */
function youtube_id_from_url($url) {
    $pattern = 
        '%^# Match any youtube URL
        (?:https?://)?  # Optional scheme. Either http or https
        (?:www\.)?      # Optional www subdomain
        (?:             # Group host alternatives
          youtu\.be/    # Either youtu.be,
        | youtube\.com  # or youtube.com
          (?:           # Group path alternatives
            /embed/     # Either /embed/
          | /v/         # or /v/
          | /watch\?v=  # or /watch\?v=
          )             # End path alternatives.
        )               # End host alternatives.
        ([\w-]{10,12})  # Allow 10-12 for 11 char youtube id.
        $%x'
        ;
    $result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    if (false !== $result) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    return false;
}

echo youtube_id_from_url('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX'); # XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what I understand is the you the XXXXXXX Part of the URL to enter into the Database after the ?v=.

In PHP you would do this using [strpos](https://www.php.net/strpos) and [substr](https://www.php.net/substr)

First you want to find the position of `?v=`

```
$YouTubeURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX';
$pos = strpos($YouTubeURL);
$pos + 3 //Add 3 to account for ?v=
```

Next Cut it at that length

```
$answer = substr($YouTubeURL, $pos);
```

This should be yoru answer or lead you to it at least. If you store this in your DB it will come out correctly in your current script. (if this is what you are trying to do.)

Comment: I don't understand. Accordding to php.net strpos() should require at least 2 parameters and in your case it should be strpos($url,"?");